# meaning of "for each of"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I am reading this [euler project question](https://projecteuler.net/problem=493) and found this sentences.

> 70 colored balls are placed in an urn, 10 for each of the seven
>   rainbow colors.

My understanding about this sentences is

> There are 70 colored balls in an urn and every 1 of 10 balls have a color in seven rainbow colors.

Is my understanding correct? else what is the correct meaning of this. Actually the second sentence is the one confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern

`for each of the {number} {nouns}`

is a kind of iterator: each item in the set of items is visited in turn.

> There are six children in your group. **For each of the children**,
>   assemble a packet with a ruler, a pencil, an eraser, and a
>   compass.

You need, in all, six rulers, six pencils, six erasers, and six compasses.

Your sentence starts with the total, and then explains how we reached the total:

> 70 colored balls are placed in an urn, 10 for each of the seven rainbow colors.

That is, 70 colored balls are placed in an urn, 10 [balls] for each of the seven rainbow colors.

Here it is in the form of an instruction:

> For each of the seven rainbow colors, place ten balls **of that color** in the urn.

Answer (score 4):

The seven rainbow colours are: red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, and violet. In the urn are ten balls of each of these colours, making 70 altogether.